# Imagemagick not working on solaris

Tags: php, imagemagick, solaris, imagemagick-convert

I am running solaris 10 coolstack with imagemagic SUMWimagick v5.4.7. Installation all went well but when I try the various ways to confirm it works I get errors such as this:

```
Test for versions and locations of ImageMagick
Path:  convert
Version return code is 137 

This should test for ImageMagick version 5.x
Path:  /usr/sfw/bin/convert
Version return code is 137 

This should test for ImageMagick version 6.x
Path:  /usr/sfw/bin/convert
Version return code is 137
```

I have also tried to use convert at console with error [sh: convert: not found] but confirmed convert is the in the path /usr/sfw/bin/convert.

I have php.ini file as follows (thinking this may be my problem):

```
include_path=/opt/coolstack/php5/lib/php:.:
extension_dir=/opt/coolstack/php5/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613
extension="mysql.so"
extension="mysqli.so"
extension="apc.so"

# hardened-php - uncomment to enable. See http://hardened-php.net
extension="suhosin.so"
extension="/usr/sfw/lib/libMagick.so"



@system("/usr/sfw/bin/convert -colorspace RGB $size".escapeshellarg($_FILES[$ufield]['tmp_name'])." ".escapeshellarg($docroot.$ufile));
```

Comment: Have you tried just running `/usr/sfw/bin/convert --version` to see what it says?  The script seems to be hiding the details necessary to debug.

Comment: Tried /usr/sfw/bin/convert --verison and got no file. But that gave me an idea to check all my path environments and once I updated those I was able to get a version. Thanks @ihsan for the direction to head in, much appreciated!

Comment: For some reason I can't seem to pass the last couple of variables to get ImageMagick to process the convert. I could use some help on where ImageMagick usually puts files while processing or afterwards.

Comment: I could also use some help on the best location to put these files. They need to be rendered in web pages via php once they are converted.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got imagemagick to work by tweaking file / dir permissions for upload dir and converted files and confirming paths to tmp file.